# Is there any way a user can close an asp.net webpage that does not trigger the page_Unload event?

Tags: asp.net

Suppose that you have a single page website with a database behind it, and you want to close all open connections to the database in the page_Unload event. Is there any way the user can close the page that doesn't trigger this event?

In other words: can you rely on the page_onUnload Handler to always execute? Assume that the server stays operational (so not something like a server that suddenly powers down while the page is open).

Comment: What are you going to do if hundreds of users open your web page and just leave it sitting there? If you want data from a database, you should get it - and close the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Page_Unload` event "is called after the page has been fully rendered, sent to the client, and is ready to be discarded". When the user opens the page, and sees it, the event has already been called. 
It is NOT called when the user leaves the page or closes the browser!

Please read about the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I see. Seems like I misunderstood the life cycle. I did read it, but I thought the "the page is ready for discarding" meant discarding as in discarded from the user's computer's memory. I thought it was a signal sent from the client to the server the client closes the page (unloads it), like Window_Close in WPF is sent when the window is closed.

Comment: No, there is no open connection, no state, no keep-alive. Once the server has delivered the page, it's over. What might be left is the SessionState server-side and the ViewState client-side.
In short, do not keep a database connection open.